# unresolved external symbol glewExperimental

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, unresolved-external

I'm trying to create a window using glew but I am getting this link error. I also tried compiling the libraries myself, which didn't work either. I also made sure that glew is properly linked.

Here's the code that's causing the error:

```
 if (configuration.api == API::OpenGL) {
      static bool sGLEWInitialized;
      if (!sGLEWInitialized) {
           glfwMakeContextCurrent(handle);
            #if WINDOWS
            glewExperimental = true;
            auto error = glewInit();

            if (error) {
                destroy_glfw_window(handle);
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize GLEW");
           }
           #endif

           sGLEWInitialized = true;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Did you check all [Common issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/799kze2z.aspx)?

Comment: yeah i checked and i put all glew libraries and linked glew32.lib and cant figure why is this error coming

Comment: What about the compiler, platform?

Comment: yes i compiled the lib for 64 bit windows using vs2015 and used under 64 bit project

Comment: In what function is an unresolved symbol? Add please the error message.

Comment: "I also made sure that glew is properly linked." This is not something you just claim. You show what you did, and let us see for ourselves whether it's proper linking or not.

Answer (score -1):

use 
glew32s.lib
glew32.lib
From
glew-2.1.0-win32\glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\x64
not 
glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\Win32

Answer (score -1):

My answer is a few years late, but if it's no longer relevant to the author, it might help someone else. This solution worked for me:

**1. If you use `vcpkg` then you need to make sure you install the static versions of the libraries.** Use the command line and do something like:

```
vcpkg.exe install glew:x64-windows-static
```

If you are using the 32-bit version, x64 should be replaced with x86 accordingly.

**2. Then in your `.vcxproj` at the bottom of the `<PropertyGroup Label=”Globals”>` section you need to add the line**:

```
<VcpkgTriplet Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">x64-windows-static</VcpkgTriplet>
```

Again, if you have a 32-bit platform, your line will look different:

```
<VcpkgTriplet Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'">x86-windows-static</VcpkgTriplet>
```

After that, you will be able to use the static versions of the libraries in your code. However, note that after you add the line to .vcxproj, you will not be able to use non-static versions of other libraries from vcpkg. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266710/how-to-use-vcpkg-packages-with-different-triplets).

**3. In the case of `glew`, you also need to add the `#define GLEW_STATIC` directive just before including the library**

**4. Also you will probably need to change the build compilation option to `/MTd` to avoid conflicts**