# How to use vcpkg packages with different triplets?

Tags: vcpkg

I have a project using 2 different packages, pkgA with triplet `x86-windows-static`, and pkgB, with triplet `x86-windows`.

When I try to compile my project, everything works fine for pkgA, since `$(VcpkgRoot)` is `%userprofile%/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows-static`, however, the headers from pkgB can't be found because they are in `%userprofile%/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows`.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I've been using vcpkg successfully, linking to everything statically (with dynamic runtime). And now I want to also use ffmpeg via vcpkg, but dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

I reached with the same issue. What I found is to write your own triplet and override a configuration for your libs. [Example](https://github.com/Intelight/vcpkg/blob/master/triplets/x86-windows-mixed.cmake).

Answer (score 2):

It is not intended to mix packages build with different triplets.

You probably want to define a custom triplet (x86-mytriplet) with per port customization (see https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md)
You can do so by copying one of the available triplets, rename it and make the desired changes in the triplet file. You can than use `vcpkg install <whatever>:x86-mytriplet`